# How to change whether an image appears on a website based a field that changed the href of that image being filled out or not

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a signature form for my company and they want people to link social media to it. Right now I have it so they enter their facebook url into a field and that changes the little facebook icon in the signature to, when clicked on, send you to their profile. However I want the little facebook icon to not appear if they don't put anything in that field.

I have tried some If Else statements but I am new to code so I am probably doing it wrong.

HTML

```
<p>Please insert the link for your Facebook profile here: <input 
    id="userFacebook" type="text" value="" 
    placeholder="https://www.facebook.com/" size="50"></p>

    <a href="#" id="outFacebook" class="face">
        <img src="facebook.png" width="25" height="25" alt="Agent 
    Facebook"></img>
```

Javascript

```
var agentFacebook = document.getElementById("userFacebook").value
    document.getElementById("outFacebook").href = agentFacebook
    if (agentSite.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("outFacebook").img.src = "facebook.png";
    } else { 
        document.getElementById("outFacebook").img.src = ""}
```

I have also tried

```
var agentFacebook = document.getElementById("userFacebook").value
document.getElementById("outFacebook").href = agentFacebook
if (agentFacebook.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("outFacebook").display = "none";
} else { 
    document.getElementById("outFacebook").display = "block"}
```

I want the image to disappear when the agent doesn't type anything into the field but show up when they do. Right now the photo always shows up and links to either their site if something is typed in or refreshed the page if nothing is input.

I have made a codepen if it helps come up with a solution. https://codepen.io/amandausr/pen/bJPpdN

Comment: The `if` statement's expression needs to be enclosed by brackets: `if agentSite == "" {...}` should be `if (agentSite == "") {...}`

Comment: Rather than changing this src of the img tag, it would be better just to toggle the visibility of the img (see css property `display` or use the `visibility` attribute on your img tag)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use an onChange event handler for the input field. Right now (as I understand it from your snippet at least) your code is only getting run once, where as you want to hide or show the image every time the user interacts with the input field. Try something like this:

```
document.getElementById("userFacebook").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    //hide or show image here
    //e is the change event
});
```

Comment: How would I go about filling the rest of that EventListener out? I am new-ish to coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can try firing a `keyup` event on your input, so whenever the value changes, the Facebook icon appears immediately. The event handler looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("userFacebook").addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
    let element = document.getElementById("facebookLogo");
    if(e.target.value == ""){
    element.classList.add("hidden");
  }else{
    element.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
});
```

And for your HTML you only need to create a class `hidden` that will hide the element when it has this class applied.

I'll leave you a fiddle so you can see what I am talking about and how this method works. Hope it solves your issue.

#### Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/k3llydev/1zo8dLs2/

Comment: Sadly this still didn't work. I could post a fiddle with all of my code as I have it so far would that help?

Comment: @amandausr surely, since that works with the code you provided. Maybe there is something else making noise with this snippet in your code.

Comment: I have added a link to a codepen of my code if you think it could possibly help?

Comment: Because your question was not clear then, what do you exactly want to do? Show only the elements that were added after the form submit?